# Can I replace Deployment Group name using Library variables in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to use Library Varibles as Azure Deployement Group name in Azure Dev-Ops Release pipelines , is it possible ? And Is it a good practise to do it ?

Purpose : I want to use same pipeline and same stage to deploy on different environments , so that If I change Deployment Group Name (Dev,QA,UAT) in library variable , it will deploy to that env.

[image: DeployementGroupName]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the Deployment Group name field doesn't support to use Pipeline Variable(e.g. Library Variable) to define the name.

It currently only supports hard-coded deployment group name in Deployment Group job.

For a workaround, you can add multiple deployment group jobs with different deployment group name. Then you can set the [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to determine which job can run
based on the Library variable value.

Here is an example:

[image]

On the other hand, I can fully understand your requirement, I suggest that you can create a suggestion ticket in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest).

Comment: Just to check if I get it right , If I create multiple deployment groups , then in DROP DOWN which group should I choose , the one where I want to deploy ? If so What is the use of expression ?

Comment: I mean that you can add multiple deployment groups with the same task and different deployment group.  In the Drop down list, you can manually select the deployment group and each deployment group job represent a deployment group. For example: deployment job 1 -> deployment group name 1 , deployment job 2 -> deployment group name 2. Then you can determine which job can run based on the library variable. If you have a small number of deployment groups, you may consider using this method